# iOS Notifications (Pusher)

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, pusher

I try to add Notifications to my iOS App using Pusher.
When I send my device token to the server I go this issue :

```
Bad HTTP response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x174032be0> { URL: https://nativepushclient-cluster1.pusher.com/client_api/v1/clients } { status code: 401, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 125;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Thu, 09 Mar 2017 10:12:22 GMT";
    Server = Cowboy;
    Via = "1.1 vegur"; } } with body: Optional("{\"error\":\"Invalid application credentials for apns\",\"desc\":\"Unable to read your certificate: failed to decrypt private key\"}\n")
```

> "{\"error\":\"Invalid application credentials for
>   apns\",\"desc\":\"Unable to read your certificate: failed to decrypt
>   private key\"

Any ideas will be strongly appreciate !
(I did have convert my certificate .p12 to .pem (certificate + key in one file, should I create two file?)

I did that :

> openssl pkcs12 -in path.p12 -out newfile.pem

Should I do :

> openssl pkcs12 -in path.p12 -out newfile.crt.pem -clcerts -nokeys
>   openssl pkcs12 -in path.p12 -out newfile.key.pem -nocerts -nodes

Many thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the tutorial from https://github.com/nomad/houston

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -out apple_push_notification.pem -nodes -clcerts
```

Comment: Sometimes you have to regenerate your provisioning profiles.